# How to read a file with long file name with unicode in Strawberry perl not using Win32::Unicode::File?

Tags: perl, unicode, character-encoding, windows-xp, strawberry-perl

I have a file located in a directory, with danish characters in it, on a Windows XP machine. I use Strawberry perl and would like to read this file. The following code works fine:

```
    use Win32::Unicode::File;
    # Some code left out....
    $fname = $mw -> getOpenFile(-filetypes=>$types);
    my $fh = Win32::Unicode::File->new;
    $fh->open('<', $fname);
```

The getOpenFile routine comes from Tk. Now for some reason Win32::Unicode::File has some unfortunate side effects that I cannot live with (it eats my memory, see ["Out of memory" with simple Win32::Unicode::File readline loop and Strawberry Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710934/out-of-memory-with-simple-win32unicodefile-readline-loop-and-strawberry-pe)). Now if I try to open the file without the Win32::Unicode::File interface I get a file not found. The reason for this is that the path gets intepreted incorrectly. I have tried converting the path according to [Perl: managing path encodings on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232397/perl-managing-path-encoding-on-windows) which doesn't work for some reason. How should I solve this? I have tried the following:

```
    use Encode;
    # Some code left out....
    $fname = $mw -> getOpenFile(-filetypes=>$types);
    my $fh;
    open($fh, '<', encode("utf8",$fname,Encode::FB_CROAK));
```

and it does not work. Any ideas?

Please forgive me if I am unclear.

Kind regards,
Michael

Comment: Alternatives: http://p3rl.org/PerlIO::fse http://p3rl.org/Path::Class::Unicode

Comment: methinks you should use UTF16 as encoding. What does $fname look like in the debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
encode("utf8"
```

Perl will be using the standard C library IO functions to open files, and on Windows where filenames are natively Unicode (UTF-16 behind the scenes) that means the library has to interpret the filename in that byte-oriented interface as being in a particular encoding.

Here's the problem: the encoding picked is never UTF-8, or any other UTF. It's the locale-specific default encoding, known (misleadingly) as the ANSI code page. On a Western Windows install that's `cp-1252`. In general you can find out what it is by calling `Win32::Codepage::get_encoding`.

So by converting your string to be in that encoding, you can access it using the native file support, *as long as* all the character in the file's path are in the ANSI code page. For Danish on a Western machine that's OK; for Danish on a Chinese machine, or vice versa, you will always get a file-not-found error.

So if you want to support filenames with all Unicode character in on Windows you have no choice but to use the Win32 API instead, as `Win32::Unicode::File` does. This isn't unique to Perl; other languages without explicit support for Unicode filenames have exactly the same problem.